# Distance between $g_i$ and $g_j$ in $G$ is greater than or equal to the distance between $f(g_i)$ and $f(g_j)$ in $H$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $\{g_1, \dotsc, g_n\}$ and let $H$ be a graph with vertex set $\{h_1, \dotsc, h_n\}$. Consider any function $f$ : $\{g_1, \dotsc, g_n\} \to \{h_1, \dotsc, h_n\}$ that has the following property: for any $i, j \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$, if $g_i$ and $g_j$ are adjacent in $G$, then $f(g_i)$ and $f(g_j)$ are adjacent in $H$.

> Prove that for any $i, j \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$, the distance between $g_i$ and $g_j$ in $G$ is greater than or equal to the distance between $f(g_i)$ and $f(g_j)$ in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\cdot|$ denote the length of a path. Let $a \to b \to c$ denote a path of shortest distance between $a$ and $c$ (so $a$ and $c$ are not connected). Then we can say
$$\begin{align}
  |a \to b \to c|\; \stackrel{1}=&\;\; |a \to b|+|b \to c| \\
                    \stackrel{2}=&\;\; |f(a) \to f(b)|+|f(b) \to f(c)| \\
                    \stackrel{3}\leq&\;\; |f(a) \to f(b) \to f(c)|\;.
\end{align}$$

1. Holds because the path from $a$ to $c$ is achieves the shortest distance of any path from $a$ to $c$.
2. Holds because $a$ and $b$ adjacent implies $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are adjacent (this assumes the graph has no loops; if our graph does have loops, we may have $f(a) = f(b)$ and this should be an inequality too).
3. Is an inequality because we may have something like $f(a)$ adjacent to $f(c)$, or even $f(a) = f(c)$.

Then we can apply this inductively to show that for any shortest path in your graph, the image of that path under $f$ must be shorter.